# PHP mail function returns false despite all the settings

Tags: php, phpmailer, html-email

I am a newbie in PHP, so all i know is actually from the forums. These are the settings i made in my php.ini file

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = engr.atiq19@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xamppnew\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
;sendmail_path = "C:\xamppnew\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

These are the changes made in sendmail.ini file

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=engr.atiq19@gmail.com
auth_password=************
force_sender=engr.atiq19@gmail.com
```

And here is the code I am using to send the mail

```
$to = "engr.atiq19@gmail.com";
$myemail = "engr.atiq19@gmail.com";    
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "my message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header('Location: ../index-alt2.html?t="done successfully"');
```

Comment: Your header redirect appears to take a 't' variable which sounds like it will be displayed on the page. Avoid this as it allows cross site scripting attacks - where someone can inject html or scripts into your page if a link is shared. If you must say if successful on the next page do not display the passed input but instead interpret the parameter server side and display a message seperately.

Comment: This is not my query. I want to know why the mail function is not working. At least how do I know the error? Cause I have used try catch exception method it is not showing me any errors. Plus I know how to handle scripts if someone tries bad things with my t variable

Comment: Which is why I didn't put my comment in the answer section. It is a side note. The safest way to deal with your t variable is to not let user input get in there in the first place. Anyway, the php error log and indeed the debug log should hopefully show you more details about your mail issue. mail() also returns if it was successful or not, so you can check that.

Comment: What is the alternate of this t variable thing? I thought it is safe once you use the test_input function of php that does not allow any script

Comment: Pass through something like `?t=success` and use an if statement in the file you are redirecting to to check it and write out a success message, like "done successfully". The key thing is to not allow user input directly on the page without being escaped. An alternative is `htmlentities()` for the t variable when writing to the page. Another alternative is using php sessions to convey the success message/flag to the next page.

Comment: What is I need to send a user_id via URL? I would need the exact id to complete the process on the receiving page. the success or done successfully are just general words that i can replace with ease using htmlentities or other techniques.

Comment: User ID is fine but probably better to use $_SESSION. Words can be exploited easily in URLs, especially for social engineering. For example what if an attacker asks people to visit this URL on your site? "/index-alt2.html?t=Thanks%20please%20visit%20badsite.com%20for%20your%20free%20prize".  Suddenly your site is asking your users to visit some other site with nefarious intent behind it. Plus, if you aren't escaping the value at all, they could place a script tag in which does something horrible. It's better to just avoid this category of expolitability altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your time and advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using PHPMailer to send email from PHP. Here's the steps to accomplish this.

1. Go to the Github [repository](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
2. Download the ZIP.
3. Extract it in your public_html directory.
4. `include '/path/to/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';` at the top of your PHP script.
5. Get the values from the HTML form like you normally would.

Here's an example...

```
index.html

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="subject">
    <input type="text" name="message">
</form>

index.php

include '/path/to/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, "ssl" also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('your email', 'your name'); // from
$mail->addAddress($email, $name); // to
$mail->isHTML(true); // if html

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message; //HTML

if($mail->send()){
    echo 'Mail sent!';
}
else {
    echo 'Mail failed!';
}
```

Comment: I did, but it won't change the votes because I do not have 15 reputations yet. How do I increase my reputations?

Comment: I did that. Can you tell me how can i increase my reputation?

Comment: Do a lot of research on any particular question you may have.